# fill an array with characters and numbers javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, angularjs

I'm working on an order form for plate registration characters on angular JS.Instead of writing down each character `(0 to 9 and a to z without i, o and u)` in an object I was hoping that there's a way to do it in a for loop; after some research I wrote from a regex:

```
this.products=[];
for (var i in /^[0-9a-fj-np-tv-z]+$/) {
    var object={};
    object.name=i;
    object.quantity=0;
    this.products.push(object);
};
```

Didn't work at all, any advices ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just write it out by hand. The code required to do the iteration would be longer (and probably slower!) than just writing it manually.

```
var symbols = 'abcdefghjklmnpqrstvwxyzABCDEFGHJKLMNPQRSTVWXYZ0123456789';
this.products = symbols.split('').map(function(s) {
    return {name: s, quantity: 0};
});
```

Edit: In re-reading your question, it seems like you want *every possible combination of letters* (your regex uses a `+`). You probably definitely don't want that, since it would crash the browser from having essentially an infinite number of combinations and fill up the user's memory. The solution I provided creates one "product" per symbol.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for, thanks a lot ! Didn't knew the .map() method, now I do